# Filtering by same day for current Month in Tableau

Tags: date, filter, tableau-api, fixed

Not sure if I am missing something on how to do this but if you wanted to filter your data on say the 12th Day of each Month, how is that achieved? I want it so that whenever it is viewed it will show the data for the 12th of the current Month.

I've tried parameter but you can only pick a date, which will not be dynamic.

I used as below in dataset:

dateadd('day',11,datetrunc('month',today()))

When I apply this to filter in sheet, it crashes the workbook.

I'm thinking how you can do this as in Excel, you can pick the day of the Month you want and it fixes it to the current Month, can tableau not do that?

I can't pick anything dynamic in the relative date range, again like 12th of "Current Month", only fixed manual dates.

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You could create a calculated field which says something along the lines of:

IF MONTH(date_field) = December THEN 'December' ELSE NULL END

Then you will have a new column in your data that shows 'December' if the condition is met. Then drag this calculated field onto your filters.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to define the following Boolean calculated field, put it on the filter shelf and select True

```
[My Date Field] = MAKEDATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 12)
```

You can use a parameter to avoid hard coding the 12 and to allow the user to select it.

Note some data sources don’t support the MAKEDATE() function. In that case, you can get a similar effect using a different function such as DATE() or DATEPARSE() to create the date, or even combining DATETRUNC() and DATEADD() to truncate today’s date to the beginning of the month and then add 11 days.

There are lots of ways to manipulate dates, pretty well described in Tableau’s online help

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the date field to filter pane, filter on the basis of "Days".
2. Select your preferred day (for instance, 12), click OK.
3. Right click on the date filter, click "Add to Context".